# Why does the following 8086 assembly code only display numbers up to 2559?

Tags: x86-16, emu8086

**What am I trying to do ?**

I want to get a 16-bit number from the user and print It on the console.

**What Is the problem ?**

Well my code works fine If the number entered Is less than 2600 but the moment I enter 2600 It displays "40" and for 2601 "41" and so on. Shouldn't It display numbers up to 65535 ? Because I am storing the value In the `bx` register which Is 16-bit and which can store at most 65535. Then why only 2559 ?

**My code:**

```
.model small
.data

msg db 10,13,'Enter a 16bit number: $'             
newline db 10,13,'$'

.code
main:

mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

mov cl, 10
mov bx, 0

mov ah, 09h
lea dx, msg
int 21h

call get16bitNum

mov ah, 09h
lea dx, newline
int 21h

mov ax, '$'

push ax

mov ax, bx      

store:  

div cl
cmp al, 0 
mov bh, 0
mov bl, ah    
push bx
je continue        
mov ah, 0
jmp store

continue:

pop ax
cmp ax, '$'
je ext 
mov bx, ax
mov ah, 02h
mov dx, bx
add dx, 48
int 21h


jmp continue

ext:        

mov ah, 04ch
int 21h

proc get16bitNum

aggregate:

mov ah, 01h 
int 21h

cmp al, 13
je return 

mov ah, 0
sub al, 48     

mov dx, bx
mov bx, ax
mov ax, dx

mul cl
add bx,ax         
jmp aggregate                        

return:

ret    

endp                

end main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You don't actually retrieve a 16-bit number!

You keep the desired input in `BX`, and so you need to multiply the whole of `BX` by 10. You do this using a **word sized multiplication**.

```
proc get16bitNum
  aggregate:
    mov  ah, 01h 
    int  21h
    cmp  al, 13
    je   return 
    mov  ah, 0
    sub  al, 48    ;AX is 0 to 9
    xchg ax, bx    ;New digit temporarily in BX
    mov  cx, 10
    mul  cx        ;Product is in DX:AX, but we won't use DX!
    add  bx ,ax    ;Add new digit
    jmp  aggregate                        
 return:
    ret
```

### You don't display the 16-bit number

The procedure to convert the number into text will definitely need to use the **word sized division**.

For an excellent explanation on how to do this see this recent post  [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos/45904076#45904076). It explains in great detail everything you need to know about converting numbers. It even uses the same technique of pushing some value in the stack (You used a **$** character for this) to know where the number ends.

ps. If you find the info in [the linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos/45904076#45904076) useful don't hesitate to upvote it. (Of course I hope you find my answer useful too!)

Answer (score 2):

**8** bit `div` produces 8 bit quotient and remainder.
When you divide 2600 by 10 you get an 8 bit quotient, losing higher bits.

You should use **16** bit division.